# updating python cryptography causes error and does not work scripts

Tags: python, pip, cryptography

I am trying to update Python cryptography, but an error occurs that does not let me run almost any script

I tried different ways to update it but it still happens from my Linux PC "ubuntu" 32bits

```
sudo pip install cryptography --upgrade
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pip", line 9, in <module>
    from pip import main
ImportError: cannot import name main
```

He tried to update it because every time he ran a series of scripts he shows me an error that he didn't do before

error message when running a script:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
          File "fbi.py", line 21, in <module>
            import requests
          File "/home/elvaquero/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/__init__.py", line 95, in <module>
            from urllib3.contrib import pyopenssl
          File "/home/elvaquero/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/urllib3/contrib/pyopenssl.py", line 46, in <module>
            import OpenSSL.SSL
          File "build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/OpenSSL/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
          File "build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/OpenSSL/SSL.py", line 194, in <module>
        AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Cryptography_HAS_SSL_ST'
```

I tried to try this

**$ apt-get --auto-remove remove python-openssl**

When trying the command

**$ pip install pyopenSSL**

Returns the following error:

```
Traceback (last most recent call):
File "/ usr / bin / pip", line 9, in <module>
from pip import main
ImportError: the name main cannot be imported
```

I Then try with

**$ sudo apt install --reinstall python-openssl**

It has been installed correctly but the error still occurs.

```
    $ python example.py
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "fbi.py", line 21, in <module>
        import requests
      File "/home/elvaquero/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/__init__.py", line 95, in <module>
        from urllib3.contrib import pyopenssl
      File "/home/elvaquero/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/urllib3/contrib/pyopenssl.py", line 46, in <module>
        import OpenSSL.SSL
      File "build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/OpenSSL/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
      File "build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/OpenSSL/SSL.py", line 194, in <module>
    AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Cryptography_HAS_SSL_ST'
```

I found that you can also try with

**$ sudo easy_install -U cffi
$ sudo easy_install -U cryptography**

But it doesn't work either

```
    $ sudo easy_install -U cffi
    Searching for cffi
    Reading https://pypi.python.org/simple/cffi/
    Best match: cffi 1.12.3
    Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/93/1a/ab8c62b5838722f29f3daffcc8d4bd61844aa9b5f437341cc890ceee483b/cffi-1.12.3.tar.gz#sha256=041c81822e9f84b1d9c401182e174996f0bae9991f33725d059b771744290774
    Processing cffi-1.12.3.tar.gz
    Writing /tmp/easy_install-2lyiDA/cffi-1.12.3/setup.cfg
    Running cffi-1.12.3/setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir /tmp/easy_install-2lyiDA/cffi-1.12.3/egg-dist-tmp-yrDbvQ
    Package libffi was not found in the pkg-config search path.
    Perhaps you should add the directory containing `libffi.pc'
    to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
    No package 'libffi' found
    Package libffi was not found in the pkg-config search path.
    Perhaps you should add the directory containing `libffi.pc'
    to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
    No package 'libffi' found
    Package libffi was not found in the pkg-config search path.
    Perhaps you should add the directory containing `libffi.pc'
    to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
    No package 'libffi' found
    Package libffi was not found in the pkg-config search path.
    Perhaps you should add the directory containing `libffi.pc'
    to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
    No package 'libffi' found
    Package libffi was not found in the pkg-config search path.
    Perhaps you should add the directory containing `libffi.pc'
    to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
    No package 'libffi' found
    c/_cffi_backend.c:2:20: fatal error: Python.h: No existe el fichero o el directorio
    compilation terminated.
    error: Setup script exited with error: command 'i686-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

```
$ sudo easy_install -U cryptography
Searching for cryptography
Reading https://pypi.python.org/simple/cryptography/
Best match: cryptography 2.7
Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/c2/95/f43d02315f4ec074219c6e3124a87eba1d2d12196c2767fadfdc07a83884/cryptography-2.7.tar.gz#sha256=e6347742ac8f35ded4a46ff835c60e68c22a536a8ae5c4422966d06946b6d4c6
Processing cryptography-2.7.tar.gz
Writing /tmp/easy_install-nKssiw/cryptography-2.7/setup.cfg
Running cryptography-2.7/setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir /tmp/easy_install-nKssiw/cryptography-2.7/egg-dist-tmp-e9llQ5
/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py:267: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'python_requires'
  warnings.warn(msg)
/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py:267: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'long_description_content_type'
  warnings.warn(msg)
no previously-included directories found matching 'docs/_build'
warning: no previously-included files found matching 'vectors'
warning: no previously-included files matching '*' found under directory 'vectors'
warning: no previously-included files found matching 'azure-pipelines.yml'
warning: no previously-included files found matching '.azure-pipelines'
warning: no previously-included files found matching '.travis.yml'
warning: no previously-included files found matching '.travis'
warning: no previously-included files matching '*' found under directory '.azure-pipelines'
warning: no previously-included files matching '*' found under directory '.travis'
warning: no previously-included files found matching 'release.py'
warning: no previously-included files found matching '.coveragerc'
warning: no previously-included files found matching 'codecov.yml'
warning: no previously-included files found matching 'dev-requirements.txt'
warning: no previously-included files found matching 'rtd-requirements.txt'
warning: no previously-included files found matching 'tox.ini'
build/temp.linux-i686-2.7/_openssl.c:22:24: fatal error: pyconfig.h: No existe el fichero o el directorio
compilation terminated.
error: Setup script exited with error: command 'i686-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+AttributeError%3A+%27module%27+object+has+no+attribute+%27Cryptography_HAS_SSL_ST%27

Comment: @phd I have updated the question, you can review it again and if necessary remove the duplicate.

Comment: Now, when your system Python is so broken, my advise is to uninstall it, completely purge all system directories related to Python, install Python again, install `pip`, `setuptools` and `virtualenv`, and from that point onward never install anything globally with `pip` (`apt` is ok). Forget `sudo` — you almost never need it for Python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are modifying your system python installation by using `sudo`. That's dangerous and you may have already modified a library that your system depends upon. Use [virtualenv](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/latest/) or [virtualenvwrapper](https://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) instead.

Here is virtualenvwrapper in action using python2:

```sh
brew@ontario:~$ mkvirtualenv -p `which python2` crypto2
Running virtualenv with interpreter /usr/local/bin/python2
New python executable in /Users/brew/.virtualenvs/crypto2/bin/python2.7
Also creating executable in /Users/brew/.virtualenvs/crypto2/bin/python
Installing setuptools, pip, wheel...
done.
virtualenvwrapper.user_scripts creating /Users/brew/.virtualenvs/crypto2/bin/predeactivate
virtualenvwrapper.user_scripts creating /Users/brew/.virtualenvs/crypto2/bin/postdeactivate
virtualenvwrapper.user_scripts creating /Users/brew/.virtualenvs/crypto2/bin/preactivate
virtualenvwrapper.user_scripts creating /Users/brew/.virtualenvs/crypto2/bin/postactivate
virtualenvwrapper.user_scripts creating /Users/brew/.virtualenvs/crypto2/bin/get_env_details
(crypto2) brew@ontario:~$ pip install --upgrade pip
DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 will reach the end of its life on January 1st, 2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 won't be maintained after that date. A future version of pip will drop support for Python 2.7. More details about Python 2 support in pip, can be found at https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/development/release-process/#python-2-support
Requirement already up-to-date: pip in ./.virtualenvs/crypto2/lib/python2.7/site-packages (19.2.2)
(crypto2) brew@ontario:~$ pip install cryptography
DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 will reach the end of its life on January 1st, 2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 won't be maintained after that date. A future version of pip will drop support for Python 2.7. More details about Python 2 support in pip, can be found at https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/development/release-process/#python-2-support
Collecting cryptography
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/e2/bf/3b641820c561aedde134e88528ba68dffe41ed238899fab7f7ef20118aaf/cryptography-2.7-cp27-cp27m-macosx_10_6_intel.whl (1.6MB)
     |################################| 1.6MB 896kB/s
Collecting enum34; python_version < "3" (from cryptography)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/c5/db/e56e6b4bbac7c4a06de1c50de6fe1ef3810018ae11732a50f15f62c7d050/enum34-1.1.6-py2-none-any.whl
Collecting cffi!=1.11.3,>=1.8 (from cryptography)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/16/f6/46a3dece43541b2cbf3776ec2299e370a2408d9380958401cacb6d101853/cffi-1.12.3-cp27-cp27m-macosx_10_6_intel.whl (245kB)
     |################################| 256kB 6.6MB/s
Collecting six>=1.4.1 (from cryptography)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/73/fb/00a976f728d0d1fecfe898238ce23f502a721c0ac0ecfedb80e0d88c64e9/six-1.12.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting asn1crypto>=0.21.0 (from cryptography)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ea/cd/35485615f45f30a510576f1a56d1e0a7ad7bd8ab5ed7cdc600ef7cd06222/asn1crypto-0.24.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting ipaddress; python_version < "3" (from cryptography)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/fc/d0/7fc3a811e011d4b388be48a0e381db8d990042df54aa4ef4599a31d39853/ipaddress-1.0.22-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting pycparser (from cffi!=1.11.3,>=1.8->cryptography)
Installing collected packages: enum34, pycparser, cffi, six, asn1crypto, ipaddress, cryptography
Successfully installed asn1crypto-0.24.0 cffi-1.12.3 cryptography-2.7 enum34-1.1.6 ipaddress-1.0.22 pycparser-2.19 six-1.12.0
(crypto2) brew@ontario:~$ deactivate
brew@ontario:~$
```

Same thing with python3:

```sh
brew@ontario:~$ mkvirtualenv -p `which python3` crypto3
Running virtualenv with interpreter /usr/local/bin/python3
Using base prefix '/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.4/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7'
New python executable in /Users/brew/.virtualenvs/crypto3/bin/python3.7
Also creating executable in /Users/brew/.virtualenvs/crypto3/bin/python
Installing setuptools, pip, wheel...
done.
virtualenvwrapper.user_scripts creating /Users/brew/.virtualenvs/crypto3/bin/predeactivate
virtualenvwrapper.user_scripts creating /Users/brew/.virtualenvs/crypto3/bin/postdeactivate
virtualenvwrapper.user_scripts creating /Users/brew/.virtualenvs/crypto3/bin/preactivate
virtualenvwrapper.user_scripts creating /Users/brew/.virtualenvs/crypto3/bin/postactivate
virtualenvwrapper.user_scripts creating /Users/brew/.virtualenvs/crypto3/bin/get_env_details
(crypto3) brew@ontario:~$ pip install --upgrade pip
Requirement already up-to-date: pip in ./.virtualenvs/crypto3/lib/python3.7/site-packages (19.2.2)
(crypto3) brew@ontario:~$ pip install cryptography
Collecting cryptography
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/63/4e/57b7a6bd98906872fcd2531e74b532de2abe17d675a5cf171931fcb4a9e8/cryptography-2.7-cp34-abi3-macosx_10_6_intel.whl
Collecting six>=1.4.1 (from cryptography)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/73/fb/00a976f728d0d1fecfe898238ce23f502a721c0ac0ecfedb80e0d88c64e9/six-1.12.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting cffi!=1.11.3,>=1.8 (from cryptography)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/f0/48/5aa4ea664eba26dd5142558d04762f5065c02220b4665b3f7eecb9bb614e/cffi-1.12.3-cp37-cp37m-macosx_10_9_x86_64.whl
Collecting asn1crypto>=0.21.0 (from cryptography)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ea/cd/35485615f45f30a510576f1a56d1e0a7ad7bd8ab5ed7cdc600ef7cd06222/asn1crypto-0.24.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting pycparser (from cffi!=1.11.3,>=1.8->cryptography)
Installing collected packages: six, pycparser, cffi, asn1crypto, cryptography
Successfully installed asn1crypto-0.24.0 cffi-1.12.3 cryptography-2.7 pycparser-2.19 six-1.12.0
(crypto3) brew@ontario:~$ deactivate 
brew@ontario:~$
```

Comment: Thanks I will work from now on in this way, I see that it will be safer and cleaner from possible errors

Comment: Cool. Best of luck @Jonaa

Answer (score 0):

Try

`apt-get --auto-remove remove python-openssl`

followed by `pip install pyopenSSL`

Comment: I have updated the question, you can review it again